# How to scroll through my JPanel that has an absolute layout?

Tags: java, layout, panel, jscrollpane, absolute

```
while (rs.next()) {
if (c == 1) {
    fillResultPanel(textFieldIMEInumber.getText().trim());
} else {
    JTextField field = createOrderIDJTextField(panelChooseOrder, i);
    field.setText(rs.getInt(1)+"");
    field.setToolTipText(rs.getString(4));
    JTextArea textArea = createOrderTextArea(panelChooseOrder, i);
    textArea.setText("Order ID" + num);
    JTextField unlockTypeField = createUnlockTypeJTextField(panelChooseOrder, i);
    unlockTypeField.setText(rs.getString(2) + " - " + rs.getString(3));

    field.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
             fillResultPanel(field.getText());
             menuListsVisibility(resultPanel);
             resetPanelVisibility(panelChooseOrder, resultPanel);
             resetComponentsContainingJTextFields(panelChooseOrder);
        }
    }); 
        searchPanel.setVisible(false);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
    }
    i += 72;
    num++;
}
```

The method `createOrderIDJTextField(panelChooseOrder, i);`creates more JTextfields than the panel dimensions, so I need to add a `JScrollPane` to scroll through them.
This is how I try to add it:

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
frmFrontPage.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "name_66584884279548");

scrollPane.setViewportView(panelChooseOrder);
```

This still does not work.

Comment: Try to set the dimensions/preferred size of the JPanel, according to its final contents .

Comment: @Berger it still does not work